# IIfNull with regexMatch in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

In Azure Data mapping, I have 3 columns for telephone numbers T1, T2 & T3.

I want to create another column TelephoneNumber that would return T1 if its not null and the value is in a certain match (to actual telephone numbers) and move on to T2 if the condition isnt met and to T3 lastly.

I tried to combine iifNull with regexMatch as follow

iifNull(
regexMatch(Telephone1,`(\+44|0044|0|44)(7)[4-9][0-9]{8}`),
regexMatch(Telephone2,`(\+44|0044|0|44)(7)[4-9][0-9]{8}`),
regexMatch(Telephone3,`(\+44|0044|0|44)(7)[4-9][0-9]{8}`)
)

But the outcome is Boolean not the Value.

Could you help please! Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr0PP.png)

Answer (score 0):

iifNull returns a Boolean value only.
So based on your requirement, you need to use a combination of iifNull and iif.